# Firestore Pagination doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I would like to fetch the documents using the Firestore pagination, but it starts all the time from the beginning.

I have already created the index for the query of `whereArrayContains` and `orderBy`. So it works perfectly when I fetch the first 10 records.

But when I would like to fetch the next 10 result, then I get back the first 10.

```
override suspend fun getShoppingLists(
    currentUser: User, coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
) = flow<Resource<MutableList<ShoppingList>>> {
    emit(Resource.Loading(true))

    val result = if(lastShoppingListResult == null) {
        shoppingListsCollectionReference
            .whereArrayContains(FRIENDSSHAREDWITH, currentUser.id)
            .orderBy(DUEDATE, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(LIMIT_10)
            .get()
            .await()
    } else {
        shoppingListsCollectionReference
            .whereArrayContains(FRIENDSSHAREDWITH, currentUser.id)
            .orderBy(DUEDATE, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .startAfter(lastShoppingListResult)
            .limit(LIMIT_10)
            .get()
            .await()
    }

    val documentsList = result.documents
    if (documentsList.size > 0) {
        lastShoppingListResult = documentsList[documentsList.size - 1]
    }

    val listOfShoppingList = mutableListOf<ShoppingList>()

    for (document in documentsList) {
        val shoppingList = document?.toObject(ShoppingList::class.java)
        shoppingList?.let {
            listOfShoppingList.add(shoppingList)
        }
    }

    emit(Resource.Success(listOfShoppingList))

}.catch { exception ->
    exception.message?.let { message ->
        emit(Resource.Error(message))
    }
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe your query gets rejected. Look at the logs, there can be something `query xxx not fulfilled` or something like this

Comment: No rejection in logs. I use the same codebase for other collections, but without the whereArrayContains filter. There it works perfectly.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, deleting `whereArrayContains()` would solve the problem here? Maybe you have a typo in there and therefore it just gives zero items for the next page

Comment: I have removed all the filters and still it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you might be interested in this article, [How to paginate Firestore using Paging 3 on Android?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution.

I'm passing the `lastShoppingListResult` variable as a nullable object into the `.startAfter()` method.

I had to cast it directly to a non nullable `DocumentSnapshot`. In this case the request works perfectly.

```
...
.startAfter(lastShoppingListResult as DocumentSnapshot)
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your findings. I spent an hour on this problem. It is a tiny but serious bug within Firebase Android SDK.